# How to sum cells which contain comments equal to a sample text?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to sum the values of cells in an Office 2013 sheet, which have a few different text comments attached to them (i.e.: "Site 1", "Site 2", etc)

This is for calculating sums of funds spent during a month on each site, which are put into the daily column cells. During a day different cells may represent different sites to which the funds have been spent. 
In the end of the month I want sum all the values of the cells with certain comment ("Site 1", for instance), next to the cell with sample text (smth like: "Site 1 = X,XXX")

I have found how to fetch the comment from a cell:

```
Function FetchComment(val) As String

On Error Resume Next
FetchComment = val.Comment.Text

End Function
```

I have also tried to adapt sumCellsByColor function to SumByComment:

```
Public Function SumByComment(DataRange As Range, CommentSample As Range) As Double

Dim Sum As Double
Application.Volatile True

  For Each cell In DataRange
    If cell.FetchComment = CommentSample.Text Then
      Sum = Sum + cell.Value
    End If
  Next cell

SumByComment = Sum

End Function
```

But it just doesn't work. How to resolve it?

Comment: what exactly is not working? have you tried stepping through your script and printing the variable values? is it crashing, or just not returning the expected output?

Comment: `If FetchComment(cell) = CommentSample.Text Then`

Comment: It returns "#NAME?" in a cell I'm putting the function in

Comment: Tim! It Worked!! Thanks!!!